# Is there any cross-platform lib to work with shell (cmd in windows) via c++?

Tags: c++, c, shell, command-line, cross-platform

Looking for cross-platform lib to work (run scripts, process results) with shell (cmd in windows) via c/c++?

Please tell anything else than `<cstdlib>`'s `system()`. I want to know if there is anything with higher level and easy for use.

Comment: Hi @David.
Can you please answer more accurately? Which class in boost should I use?

Comment: cross-platform, does it mean Across all versions of windows?

Comment: Of course NO! It means for win, mac, linux, solaris e.t.c (all well known platforms)

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the standard library? Is it missing features that you need? What do you mean by "higher level"?

Comment: I want find well written wrapper on system. Which allows high level working with stdout, stdin, stderr, status of command... Of course I can use stdlib, but If there is something good I would like to know.

Comment: You still haven't explained **why** you want a high level wrapper over commands that already exist in the standard library. If you're looking for high level things, choosing to write the program in C or C++ in the first place is getting off to the wrong start.

Comment: Now I'm just investigating everithing what I can find in this sphere. This doesn't mean, that I will chose higher level one. I just want to know what alternatives there is exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used [boost.process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/) since 0.1
It is not officially included in boost mainstream, but seems to have reached a well tested state and seems to be on the point to be included.

my2c

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little heavy-weight for just shell processing, but I find http://qt.nokia.com a very useful cross-platform library that will fulfill all needs from launching processes to parsing output and much more. And I find it easy to use and quite well documented. You could probably limit yourself to using the core Qt library if you are not interested in Qt's cross-platform widget lib.

Relevant in this case:

- [QProcess](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qprocess.html#details)
- [QTextStream](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtextstream.html#details)

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit about Qt's support for command line interfaces? I wasn't aware that it provided any sort of shell classes.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Tilman, but QT is big and not sure that usefull.

Comment: @cody-gray Maybe I don't understand what you mean by shell classes. I was just thinking of launching a process (possibly `cmd.exe`) and attaching to stdin/stdout. There are convenient classes for this, specifically, see [QProcess](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qprocess.html#details). Thanks to Qt's signal/slot mechanism, everything can easily be handled asynchronously if desired.